# Partition of $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-partition

Is it possible to create a numerable partition of $[a,b]$? Because I think that it isn't possible, because the last point of the partition must be $b$. But I use the function defined in $[0,1]$ that:
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \mbox{ if } t\in \left[\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]
$$
I can't create a partition in order to have a point of the partition in every set where $f(t)$ changes its value. What do you think? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is a "numerable" partition?

Comment: With infinity parts. Maybe the right word is countable, isn't it? Sorry!

Comment: How about letting each rational number in the interval be in its own singleton set, and then adding a single set containing all of the irrationals? That's denumerably many sets that partition $[a,b]$.

Comment: I get your idea, but it seems like you never "arrive" to 1. I know, it is stupid what I'm saying...

Comment: What do you mean by "arriving"? One of the sets is $\{1\}$ since $1$ is rational. It's right there. You know that $\mathbb Q$ is countable, right? Otherwise just take $\left\{a+\frac{b-a}{n}\right\}$ as your singletons for each $n\ge 1$ and let the zeroth set set contain everything that _doesn't_ have that form.

Comment: Ok, but i can't right the partition like this:
$a=t_0<\ldots<t_N=b$. That's what i mean

Comment: Usually a "partitioning" is just a set of pairwise-disjoint subsets whose unions is the given set. There's nothing about ordering implied by the term.

Comment: Right, I'm a bit confused because in the definition of BV functions you have to work with finite partitions but sometimes you need a denumerable partition in order to get the total variation. Or maybe I'm wrong about this, too. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Oh -- in that context it looks like (from a cursory review of the Wikipedia article) "partition" is used as a sloppy shorthand for "partitioning into intervals". In that case my examples aren't examples.

Comment: So my idea is acceptable in that context?